Can someone suggest an SMTP server that has an easy setup
Can someone suggest an SMTP server that has an easy setup? I have tried with open source packages, but nothing works.
Note : I don't need  cloud based services I need an smtp server.
I have tried with maddy mail server , casquid , postfix etc

I am sure they all work.  If you have an issue setting them up, then I suspect you will still have the issues with other packages.  Have you thought about asking for help in the appropriate forums?

You could post the issue you are facing when setting up, may be that will help

I intended to post this as a comment but for want of of reputation, I am unable to do so and hence posted as answer


Error: Recipient command failed: 454 4.7.1 roshan.g@domain.com: Relay access denied
response: '454 4.7.1 roshan.g@domain.com: Relay access denied',
responseCode: 454,
command: 'RCPT TO',
recipient: 'sd.g@domain.com'
but i have configured it on postfix and when i send it via echo  it is working  comment but i can't do it via node js.
